# doing math in two different file in linux

Tags: linux, awk

I have two data file each of them has 3 columns. How can I divided the corresponding elements in third columns in these two files and write it in another file in linux or awk.

```
Experiment Replica Mean
General0 0 408.5
General0 1 461.162
General0 2 428.23
General0 3 373.771
General0 4 396.243

Experiment Replica Mean
General0 0 124.674
General0 1 142.017
General0 2 145.206
General0 3 118.493
General0 4 126.985

Experiment Replica Mean
General0 0 124.674 / 408.5
General0 1 
General0 2 
General0 3 
General0 4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next}FNR==1{print;next}{print $1,$2,$3/a[$1,$2]}' f1 f2
Experiment Replica Mean
General0 0 0.3052
General0 1 0.307955
General0 2 0.339084
General0 3 0.31702
General0 4 0.320473
```

Tip: `column -t` is a nice tool for formatting your output into a table:

```
awk .... | column -t
Experiment  Replica  Mean
General0    0        0.3052
General0    1        0.307955
General0    2        0.339084
General0    3        0.31702
General0    4        0.320473
```

**Explanation:**

```
FNR==NR {            # FNR==NR is only true in the first file 
    a[$1,$2]=$3      # Build array, keys are field 1 and 2, value is field 3
    next             # Skip to the next line in the file
}
FNR==1 {             # If we are on the first line in the second file
    print            # Print the line
    next             # Go grab the next line
}
{
    x=$3/a[$1,$2]    # Do the math (the value of a[$1,$2] is $3 from file1)
    print $1,$2,x    # print the output
}
```

To run the script in this form save it to a file `script.awk` and do `awk -f script.awk f1 f2`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit this code because I need to multiply the third column to 100.

Comment: @user2312186 I have added the long version of the script with comments. Hope this is clear. To do the multiplication would be simple `x=($3/a[$1,$2])*100`. If this answer solves your problem please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that corresponding records occur at identical positions in both files, the files can be pasted together

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | 
awk '/Mean/{print($1, $2, $3)} ! /Mean/ {print($1, $2, $6/$3)}'

Experiment Replica Mean
General0 0 0.3052
General0 1 0.307955
General0 2 0.339084
General0 3 0.31702
General0 4 0.320473
```

Here's sudo_O's classy version of the above:

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | awk '{print $1,$2,/Mean/?$3:$6/$3}'
```

Comment: *F.Y.I* Print is not a function in `awk`.

Comment: @sudo_O, I tested this on `GNU Awk 4.0.1` and it worked fine.

Comment: I did not say your script was invalid, I was simply pointing out the brackets are redundant as `print` is a statement in `awk` not a function. You are printing `($1, $2, $3)` which is identical to `$1, $2, $3`.

Comment: Here's how I would I have written it `awk '{print $1,$2,/Mean/?$3:$6/$3}'`

Comment: @sudo_O, that's awesome. Adding it in